# Spouse have French and Swedish nationality which residence permit non EU should apply?

Tags: residency, weddings, french-citizens, swedish-citizens

I am non EU, we did marriage in Sri Lanka. My wife having Swedish passport now working in France, so I applied my long stay Visa application as a spouse of European National, to live in France, they issued me short stay visa (3 months) and told you come and apply your residence permit in prefecture. Now I am in France. It is normal process but now we found out that she is also having valid French ID Card as she born in France but after she moved Sweden and lived there until recently, so we don't know that my application as a spouse of EU national will work or not.

On another hand if I will present my application as a spouse of French national, there are 2 main difficulties, which are mentioned in embassy sites and other locations :

Spouse of French national must have long stay visa (more than 3 months) to able to apply residence permit. (which I don't have)

Marriage must be register in France. I don’t know how to register our marriage in France because I have only 2 weeks left in my short stay Visa.

Any idea would be great!

Comment: You are right I just noticed, should I remove question from here? because I am posting my question in Expats

Comment: Are you sure about the citizenship? Merely being born in France usually isn't enough to become a French citizen.

Comment: Yes she born in France from French father, most importantly she is having valid French ID Card

Comment: @gockel Yes, you're right, being French is what matters. The thing that confused me is that in this scenario she is actually French because she has a French father. Being born in France is not enough, being born abroad is generally not a problem if you have a French parent.